# adding jar to libraries not working for redis

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am trying to add a package for redis to Java. I am very new to java and am following this tutorial with netbeans IDE

[Tutorial that I am following http://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_java.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_java.htm)

However when I try to build I get the following error

```
error: package redis.clients.jedis does not exist
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
```

here are some screenshots that show that I have added that package

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*-sources.jar` files do not contain compiled code, they contain the source code, to be used for debugging (mostly). To make your code work, you will need to add the proper jar to build path, in this case that would be `jedis-2.1.0.jar`. You can download it from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/redis/clients/jedis/2.1.0/jedis-2.1.0.jar).